# version issue with hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am using Eclipse Luna.
I made a maven project using hibernate core 4.3.6:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

(I tried more recent versions with the same result).
I set my hibernate configuration (edit configuration in hibernate perspective) to hibernate 4.0.
When running the project,

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
```

returns :"3.5.6-Final" instead of 4.0 something as I would expect.
I would not mind so much but this consequently causes compilation errors in my HibernateUtil class:

```
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

is not accepted as eclipse apparently only knows the older version :

```
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); //no argument.
```

Any idea how to force eclipse to use a post 3.5 hibernate configuration?
Once again, I tried to include other versions with maven (more recent than 4.3.6) with no success....

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you done a Maven Update? In Eclipse Rightclick -> Maven -> Update (or Alt + F5)?

Comment: Rightclick on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab -> Open maven dependencies - search for your hibernate-core jar and check the version, which one is displaying? Do you maybe have multiple hibernate-core jars?

Comment: Found!
There was a hard copy of hibernate3 into WebContent\WEB-INF\lib
So although Maven was up to date at 4.3.6, the hard copy was somehow loaded and misbehaved. Thx for helping me finding out! :)

Comment: Glad you got that sorted out ;)